# How do to uninstall windows updates, from a prompt or PS in Hyper-V server?

Tags: windows-update, hyper-v-server-2008-r2

I'm having an issue on my server when working with my VM guests, and I think its due to a recently installed update. What is the correct command to uninstall Windows Updates from either the command prompt, or Powershell?

Answer (score 28, accepted):

To obtain a list of installed patches you can do:

```
wmic qfe list
```

To uninstall a listed patch, you do:

```
wusa /uninstall /kb:<kbnumber>
```

Here are some links with more information:
http://www.systemcentercentral.com/BlogDetails/tabid/143/indexid/57960/Default.aspx
http://support.microsoft.com/kb/934307
http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd883262(WS.10).aspx

Note: the 934307 KB article says that you can't use /uninstall on Windows 2008 - this does not apply to Windows 2008 R2 - they enabled the uninstall switch on R2 (see the last link).

Comment: Or to retrieve the list of installed patched in PowerShell: Get-Hotfix

Answer (score 7):

Since I just ran into this, and it's not clear from the documentation, when using `wusa /uninstall /kb:<kb number>` make sure you're using the actual ***number*** from the KB, not the number **and** the KB.

Wrong: `wusa /uninstall /kb:KB123456`

Right: `wusa /uninstall /kb:123456`

Answer (score 3):

And to do it from a remote computer :
wmic /node:SRVNAME process call create "powershell wusa /uninstall /kb:2639043 /quiet /norestart"

and wusa /? to have more information on parameters

Answer (score 0):

On Windows 10 the /quiet no longer works. You may use:

```
$SearchUpdates = dism /online /get-packages | findstr "Package_for"
$updates = $SearchUpdates.replace("Package Identity : ", "") | findstr "KBXXXXXX"
#$updates
DISM.exe /Online /Remove-Package /PackageName:$updates /quiet /norestart
```

see: https://social.technet.microsoft.com/Forums/windows/en-US/f6594e00-2400-4276-85a1-fb06485b53e6/issues-with-wusaexe-and-windows-10-enterprise?forum=win10itprogeneral

Answer (score 0):

Try this in CMD or PS

```
wmic qfe list brief /format:table
```

Comment: Try to explain your command a bit,

Comment: PS command is Get-Hotfix